# How to force parent controller to reload data?

Tags: angularjs, controller

I am trying to force parent controller to reload data after I update those data in his child controller. 
The Html :

```
 <div ng-controller='parentCtr'>
       {{data}}
       <mydirective></mydirective>
    </div>
```

The data in the parentCtr is from server by calling service like this:

```
    function parentCtr(){
      $scope.data=someservice.getDate();
    }
  in mydirective:  function childCtr(){
      // do something to update data and save in the same server.
     someservice.update(data);
}
```

What I need is after someservice.update() success, I need to parent level refresh the data and show my update info.

Comment: Could you add and exemple of how you use your service ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by this way. Emit a message when the call is success and listen the message in parent controller to refresh the state or page.

```
    function parentCtr($scope,$state){
                  $scope.data=someservice.getDate();
                  $scope.$on('refreshParent', function(){
                     $state.reload(); //reload the state
           })
                }

 function childCtr($scope){
                  // do something to update data and save in the same server.
                 someservice.update(data).then(function(){
                 //emit a message when success 
                 $scope.$emit('refreshParent');
        });
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call service like this

```js
   someService.update(data).then(function (response) {
                   
     recal funcation to load data
                },
          function (err) {})
```

Comment: You mean I need to recall the data load function in the update success? so in this case, May I need to set scope: false in ChildCtr? otherwise how parentCtr knows there is data reload in the childCtr? Because in the ParentCtr I need to assign those data to $scope.data which is defined in parentCtr

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass a function to the directive's scope. For example:

```
   (function() {
   'use strict';
   angular
       .module('myApp', []);

   function myCtrl($scope){
       $scope.controllerFn = function(){
           console.log('Fired by directive');
       };
   }

   function mydirective() {
       return {
           restrict: 'AE',
           scope: {
               parentFunction: '='
           },
           controller: function($scope, someservice) {
               var data = {};
               someservice
                   .update(data)
                   .then($scope.parentFunction, null);
           }
       };
   }

   angular
       .module('myApp')
       .controller('myCtrl', myCtrl)
       .directive('mydirective', mydirective);
  }());


  <div ng-controller='myCtrl'>
     <mydirective parent-function="controllerFn()"></mydirective>
  </div>
```

Comment: but it will create isolate scope, the thing is I need some other data from parentCtr, I need to set scope: false.